Apache Airflow dockerOperator delay while running commands
I've encountered an issue where there sometimes are a delay in my dockerOperators which seems to show up "randomly", but the delay is always of some modulo of 60 seconds (so 60s, 120s, and even 180s sometimes). See attached image of gantt view. The actual commands just take a few seconds and in some of the operators the entire operator is done in seconds. But as can be seen from the log there is sometimes 60 seconds between some of the steps, where normally there should only be maybe 1 second.
It seems to be something like a heartbeat of 60 seconds where it is waiting to execute or continue, but it is all within the same dockerOperator command and after it is already running (the actual broker heartbeat is 120 seconds so not related).


We have dived into logs and all the settings which could be relevant, but have not found anything that we can modify to make the execution time more consistent.
